# Windows Form App With Inline Assembly Code

Tags: c++-cli, inline-assembly

I am very confused and frustrated, I am in an assembly programming class and am tasked with modifying an example from the textbook for one on my assignment problems. The example is a simple string encrypter which uses inline assembly to modify characters from an input string one-by-one and print it back out in another textbox within a windows form.

I wrote everything exactly as it is in the text and no dice Visual Studio will not build it and tons of build errors are thrown. I don't understand what I am doing wrong, and it is frustrating when I cannot practically apply something that is demonstrated in the text.

Here is the example code:
[Windows Form Data Encryption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gYUI.png)

And here is what I have which is in the header file .h that is part of the form design:

```
#pragma once

char EncryptionKey = 0x45;
char Encrypt(char code) 
{
    _asm
    {
        mov a1, code
        xor a1, EncryptionKey
        mov code, a1
        mov a1, EncryptionKey
        inc a1
        and a1, 7fh
        mov EncryptionKey, a1
    }
    return code;
}

namespace TextEncryter {
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    ///
    /// WARNING: If you change the name of this class, you will need to change the
    ///          'Resource File Name' property for the managed resource compiler tool
    ///          associated with all .resx files this class depends on.  Otherwise,
    ///          the designers will not be able to interact properly with localized
    ///          resources associated with this form.
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  Encrypt;
    protected: 

    private: System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox^  richTextBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox^  richTextBox2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;
    protected: 

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->Encrypt = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->richTextBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox());
            this->richTextBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox());
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // Encrypt
            // 
            this->Encrypt->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->Encrypt->Location = System::Drawing::Point(197, 249);
            this->Encrypt->Name = L"Encrypt";
            this->Encrypt->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->Encrypt->TabIndex = 0;
            this->Encrypt->Text = L"Encrypt";
            this->Encrypt->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->Encrypt->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Encrypt_Click);
            // 
            // richTextBox1
            // 
            this->richTextBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(13, 22);
            this->richTextBox1->Name = L"richTextBox1";
            this->richTextBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(259, 96);
            this->richTextBox1->TabIndex = 1;
            this->richTextBox1->Text = L"";
            // 
            // richTextBox2
            // 
            this->richTextBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(13, 138);
            this->richTextBox2->Name = L"richTextBox2";
            this->richTextBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(259, 96);
            this->richTextBox2->TabIndex = 2;
            this->richTextBox2->Text = L"";
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(13, 3);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(36, 16);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 3;
            this->label1->Text = L"Input";
            this->label1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::label1_Click);
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this->label2->AutoSize = true;
            this->label2->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(10, 121);
            this->label2->Name = L"label2";
            this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(98, 16);
            this->label2->TabIndex = 4;
            this->label2->Text = L"Encrypted Text";
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 284);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->richTextBox2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->richTextBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->Encrypt);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion

*private: System::Void Encrypt_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
         {
            richTextBox1->Text = "";
            for (int a = 0; a < textBox1->Text->Length; a++)
            {
                richTextBox1->Text += Convert::ToChar(Encrypt(textBox1->Text[a]));
            }
         }*
};
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2008 Express. When I try and use a newer version of visual studio windows forms are based on C# and not C++ and I can't even get it to build as far as in 2008. The main errors that are thrown are:

1>        Inline native assembly not supported in managed code

error C3862: 'Encrypt': cannot compile an unmanaged function with /clr:pure or /clr:safe

C2227: left of '->Text' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>        type is ''unknown-type''

Do I maybe need to put the char Encrypt function within the .ccp source file that belongs to the project? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Windows Forms can use C++/CLI, which is not the same as C++. As the errors tell you, you cannot compile inline assembly in Pure CLR mode. You can try turning off pure clr mode in the project settings, or put the code that requires inline assembly into its own project that gets linked to your Windows Forms project

Comment: You could write a pure ASM file, assemble it with an assembler and link the resulting object file. As an alternative approach to inline ASM.

Comment: #pragma managed(push, off) before it, #pragma managed(pop) after it.